# When apple replaces the battery in a 15" MBP retina, do they replace the entire top portion of the case?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, trackpad

Apple's site says it is $199 to replace the battery.   Do the techs replace the entire top portion of the case including  the keyboard and trackpad?   I've read a few things on the internet alluding to that since the battery is glued in, they replace the entire assembly.

Just wondering if this includes the keyboard and track pad.   (I think it must include the keyboard since it is riveted in).  I'm wondering specifically about the trackpad, since mine has been flaky for a while, and now battery is about due for replacement.

Mine is a mid 2012 macbook pro retina.

Update:  Had this done, and for the low price of $199 I got a new keyboard, trackpad and topcase as part of the deal, as expected.   I can't believe how worn out my old keyboard was!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears to be the case that Apple will replace the top case assembly if you want to replace your battery.

> As first reported by Treehugger, which received a copy of an Apple internal service document for the "Mid-2012" 15-Inch Retina Display MacBook Pro, Apple informs its own service personnel that "batteries must be replaced with the top case assembly" and that "the battery alone is not a replaceable part." EveryMac.com also has been provided with copies of the internal service documents for subsequent 15-Inch Retina Display MacBook Pro models and although there are internal differences, the battery design effectively is the same.
>
> Additionally, Apple warns its own technicians that "batteries should
>   not be separated from the top case assembly for any reason," as
>   attempting to do so could puncture the battery and lead to fire or
>   injury. Do not attempt to pry the battery apart from the top case.

Source:  [EveryMac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-retina-display-faq/macbook-pro-retina-display-how-to-replace-battery.html)

According to [iFixit](http://ifixit.org/blog/2983/repairing-the-unrepairable-macbook-pro-with-retina-display-repair-guides/), it will cost local repair shops around $500 to source the top case assembly to replace the battery.

IFixit.com also has [instructions on how to remove this battery](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Battery+and+Trackpad.+Disassembling+MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+2012+2013+2014+2015/51846) should you want to replace it.  [Batteries with a minimum of 12 month warranties](http://radnex.us/macbook-pro-retina-2012-2013-battery) can be had for $90USD makes this a worthwhile consideration.  Keep in mind that this is a difficult repair and if you are unsure of your ability to tackle something like this, best hand it over to a pro.

Comment: I just had this done for a 2015 model, one for which there had been a recall. The battery packs had gotten all "puffy" from leaks. I had opened the bottom to blow out dust and after doing so, that allowed further escape and warped the MacBook after I re-attached the bottom. They fixed it 2 days at the Apple Store, no charge, due to the recall, replaced the top case assembly, and BTW the repair was valued right around $500 according to the receipt, but free due to the recall.

Answer (score 2):

The battery is glued to the top part.  In the Apple's internal instruction to employees, it is strongly advised not to attempt separating the battery from the top case.  Your entire top case will be replaced, which includes the battery, the keyboard, and the track pad.

Answer (score -2):

There wouldn't be a need to replace the keyboard and trackpad unless during the battery replacement they damage it.

Check out this [iFixit guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Battery+and+Trackpad.+Disassembling+MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+2012+2013+2014+2015/51846) to see how they remove the battery