# How to disable the power management of the CPU on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, performance, power, cpu

Since few days the battery of my MacBook Pro (Retina 15 inch, running macOS Sierra 10.12.4) is not working anymore.

Since then, my computer performance is really bad: everything is slow and freezing, a bit like when the battery is under 5%.

I tried to disable this power consumption feature. After some research on the internet I found the command `pmset -b reduce 0` which is suppose to disable the reduction of the CPU consumption.

```
sh-3.2# pmset -b reduce 0
Usage: pmset <options>
See pmset(1) for details: 'man pmset'
```

But as you can see it's not working. Any idea how could I disable the CPU reduction?

Comment: Maybe the reduce option was removed in 10.12? What does it show in the man page `man pmset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the man page for pmset (`man pmset`)  on macOS 10.11 - El Capitan for anything related to reducing CPU speed yielded no results; though I was able to find an [Apple discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1814248?start=0&tstart=0) dating back to 2008.

I suspect that the user ability to regulate CPU speed was removed at some point.

That said, the issue is that you have a failing/failed battery and it needs to be replaced.  Your CPU is throttling itself down becuase it has detected low reserves in your battery and is close to shutting down; this is by design.

You didn't mention which specific model you had, but generically speaking, you will have to [get the top case replaced](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231914/119271).

However, [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Battery+and+Trackpad.+Disassembling+MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+2012+2013+2014+2015/51846) has some instructions on how to replace the battery without replacing the entire top case.  ***Warning:***  It's difficult and involves at lot of work to release the adhesive holding the battery in place.