# Swollen battery for the past few days - MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery

I checked with [Macbook Pro mid-2015 15" swollen battery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/359218) and I am asking this question. My MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015), details enclosed, is working perfectly. For the past two days I noticed a strange bulge in the bottom and the lid isn't closing correctly.

[image]

[image: My Mac]

I have been handling it really carefully - dust free, never dropped down, etc. And here are some more information about the machine. **Should I continue using it with the bulge or should I do anything to reduce the bulge?** As this is my only source of income with the work I do here and there's no alternate for me.

I always use it in a clamshell mode (lid closed, power connected, external monitor, keyboard and mouse always connected). I cannot remove the power cable, if I do so, the system switches off in [clamshell mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201834).

> To use closed-display mode with your Mac notebook, here's what you need:
>
> - An AC power adapter or an external display that provides power over USB-C or Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C).
> - An external keyboard and mouse or trackpad, either USB or wireless.
> - A [USB-C to USB adapter](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204360) or cable if you're using a USB mouse or keyboard with a [Mac that has USB-C ports](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201736).
> - An external display or projector.

I have been using my MacBook Pro in the above setup for about three years. It's been 39 months since I bought it and here's the **Battery Information:**

```
Model Information:
    Serial Number:  D86XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    Manufacturer:   SMP
    Device Name:    bqXXXXXX
    Pack Lot Code:  0
    PCB Lot Code:   0
    Firmware Version:   702
    Hardware Revision:  1
    Cell Revision:  3244
Charge Information:
    Charge Remaining (mAh): 8623
    Fully Charged:  Yes
    Charging:   No
    Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 8909
Health Information:
    Cycle Count:    8
    Condition:  Normal
Battery Installed:  Yes
Amperage (mA):  0
Voltage (mV):   12817

AC Charger Information:
    Connected:  Yes
    ID: 0x0aa1
    Wattage (W):    85
    Family: 0x0085
    Serial Number:  0x00XXXXXX
    Charging:   No
```

I recently installed coconutBattery and here are some details about that.

[image: coconutBattery]

The cycle count is also very less. I am not sure why it got so much swollen and it also affects the trackpad and other things, I really hope it doesn't come out breaking. Should I continue using? I have booked an appointment with AASP on Monday, but I do have a heavy usage on this weekend - tomorrow and day after. Geographically, I am in London, if it helps. Please advice me.

Happy to provide more information if possible.

Comment: **Update #1:** I have gone to Apple Authorised Service Centre and they have quoted me around 700 £ for all the replacement. I am going to check with an Apple Store and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely locate a service provider that can run a test today / tomorrow. Remote service is easy for this and quick and consider getting a backup and then take your computer to the Apple Store if they are open in your country.

- https://locate.apple.com
- https://support.apple.com/15-inch-macbook-pro-battery-recall

This is the battery airbag inflating to prevent a problem like fire or failure. Protect your data immediately, the hardware also needs attention. You may be covered by a [safety program](https://www.loveios.net/2019/07/causes-and-precautions-of-swollen.html) about the Apple batteries in the MacBook and it has precautions to take. In the past, these original batteries have exploded. I would take it to Apple Store immediately.

Also if the battery continues to swell it will eventually break something inside your computer. Others have mentioned that a swollen battery broke the trackpad on their MacBook Pro. All the more reason to take it to an Apple Store even if you think you are out of warranty. This design is like crumple zones in a car - the hardware is designed to save life in the event the design tolerances are exceeded. If the car is going to crash, it might as well do so safely. Same with a battery, if it’s getting over charged, it might as well let you know clearly and safely.

I also found this [fairly recent (2019) article](https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/20/18693136/apple-recall-2015-15-inch-macbook-pro-battery-overheat-fire-risk-safety) about Lithium Polymer batteries and off-gassing.

Comment: Yes, no hardware changes since buying (on March 2017) from an Apple Store. I'll check the article.

Comment: ouch, good catch. Thanks... i have edited my answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman: I edited my answer to include an article you should read about MacBook Pro from 2015...

Comment: Alright, you're scaring me. I'll better switch it off right away and do something about this!  I'll need to wait till Monday to get this poor thing admitted int he hospital.

Comment: And regarding that other article, my MacBook Pro serial number says it's either not coming under the affected thing or it's already serviced. It's just been 8 cycles! 

Comment: Thats good news!!!

Comment: I just noticed the part where you ask if you should do anything to reduce the swelling. I don't think there is anything you can do other than let it cool off if it will.

Comment: So would I get a free consultation or is it gonna be expensive. I'm scared about that too. Any idea?

Comment: They shouldn't charge you for looking at your Mac. I'd guess they tell you the battery needs replacing which is around $50-$75 dollars I think. They may replace it for free due to the problems others have had. And point out the existing battery has only 8 cycles.  I've never had this problem so I'm just speculating.

Comment: Thanks that's it. I'll try this and keep you updated. Of this is exactly what I do, I'm gonna accept your answer. You are awesome! Thanks a lot

Comment: I edited this. Good news @PraveenKumarPurushothaman just ask Apple service to get details. They will be able to tell who made the battery, if it’s genuine and look for any reason for Apple to pay for the repair.

Comment: Ok thank you so much. If this is what I'm going to do, I will be accepting your answer as soon as possible after the series of events and I will also keep you updated about what is happening. Thanks for your patient advice. Also let me know is it ok if I continue to use my Mac for this weekend?

Comment: Your welcome and yes keep me posted please. I sure hope this works out well for you.  If you want you could try a Certified Apple Repair Center if you can't get to Apple Store or its too crowded.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I would not leave it anywhere you can’t afford a fire. Get a backup, turn it off. The chance is low, but what if the swelling caused a short. The battery has enough energy to ignite. I’ve seen probably 500 macs in that state (I used to repair them) and zero had a fire, the odds are super, super low. But you can’t know. Watch it until you know Apple says it’s safe or you’ve removed that battery and disposed of it safely. That battery has to go now that it started swelling.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for that insight @bmike. I'll switch it off and cool it. Is there no way I can reduce the swelling at all?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman, RE: "Is there no way I can reduce the swelling at all?" -- In this situation, no, replacing the battery is what needs to be done!

Comment: @bmike Looking at your edits, I need to stress the fact that I have kept the batteries always powered on and charging. Is it bad? Doesn't Apple batteries have circuitries that prevent the overcharge and thermal runaway?

Comment: Hey all, went into the Apple Store and came out with a 400 £ bill. Anyway, this is not my fault, but I am gonna ask Apple once again to see if they can do something for a student discount or something.

Comment: what was the problem?