# Mcabook Pro aluminum bottom cover bent - from battery overheating?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, hardware

[image: Macbook Pro battery]I have a Macbook Pro Early 2015, model A1502, that I opened up recently because I was worried about a wobble that I saw. I don't use this laptop as much anymore but in the past, I had noticed that it tended to overheat a lot so I was worried that there might be a problem with the battery. Before opening it, I checked the battery health and it was around 600 cycles, with a life span of 1000 cycles. After opening it, I didn't seen much swelling from the battery and figured it was fine.

But when I was putting the bottom cover back on, I felt a lot of resistance/tension in the cover and figured that something was in the way of the cover and preventing it from lining up with screws grooves.

Should I replace the battery or is it okay to use as is?

Comment: Swollen batteries are not safe - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359218/macbook-pro-mid-2015-15-swollen-battery

Comment: At the very least, some photos would be useful. Otherwise we're just guessing. It could be a swollen battery, or it could be that you've not seated it properly. However, a 6-year-old battery is at the end of its life, regardless of cycles.

Comment: @benwiggy - those batteries are glued in, so unless a solvent or heat removal process was employed, the battery cannot be mis-seated. - https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Early+2015+Battery+Replacement/45137

Comment: Fair point. However, something could be mis-seated. I'm just thinking of possibilities, in the absence of info.

Comment: I know that Apple has established a recall program for some computers, Macbook Pros from 2016 and 2017, but my computer doesn't fall within that range and isn't eligible for the free battery replacement.

Comment: Since you added the photo… Batteries should not look like a box of pillows… that needs urgent replacement.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.