# 2018 Macbook pro keyboard dimensions - touchbar vs non touchbar

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have a 2018 13" Macbook Pro without a touchbar. It has a UK spec keyboard and I'd like to use it in Germany where I often need to type characters with umlauts. So I will change my input source to German and this remaps the keys (for example `:` gets mapped to `ö`).

In addition, I wanted to add keyboard cover like this one: https://www.kaufland.de/product/327867795/?utm_source=shopping&utm_medium=non-paid&utm_campaign=pricecomparison&sid=24974677. I would use this cover and select the German keyboard option in my settings. Trouble is, this is for the touchbar model and mine doesn't have a touchbar. I couldn't find a similar product for non-toucbar models.

My question is: Would the cover meant for the touchbar model work on the non-touchbar model? That is, excluding the top row of keys, is the rest of the keyboard the same size in touchbar and non-touchbar models?

Comment: MacBooks aren’t spec’d for different keyboards and the keyboards don’t have different dimensions - just the language and layout differs.

Comment: I understand, but the question here is touchbar vs non-touchbar keyboard dimensions. Is the size of the touchbar exactly the same as the top row of keys in the non-touchbar model?

Comment: Actually, you can’t replace the keyboard by itself.  You have to get the entire [*top case assembly*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231914/119271) which includes a battery and the touchbar components.  If you want the German layout (ANSI or ISO), you’ll have to get the German top case

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood your point but what I was buying was a keyboard cover (with German keyboard layout), putting it on my British keyboard and changing my keyboard's input source to German. Changing my keyboard's input source would map, for example the ":" key on the keyboard to "ö". The keyboard cover would then match the new mapping. I edited the question to clarify this, apologies if it wasn't clear before.

Comment: You should consider a BT keyboard

Comment: Ahh.  You should reword the question because it reads like two different questions.   When buying the cover, you have to choose one the works with/without Touch Bar.  I don’t think the dimensions of the keyboards are published anywhere. However, a certified Apple accessory manufacturer would they would reference the Touch Bar for simplicity